# SQL Server 2016 - Get sys.assembly_files by database name

Tags: sql, sql-server, .net-assembly

I have a database that has a .Net CLR assembly added to it.

When I execute the below query by selecting that particular database, I get the assembly in the results.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.assembly_files
```

But when I execute the same above query by selecting any other database like master, I do not get the assembly in the results.

Is there any way to get the assembly in results by selecting the master database and passing the other database name in the query which has the assembly?

Comment: Just use 3 part naming. `SELECT * FROM YourDatabase.sys.assembly_files;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use

```
SELECT <cols> FROM database_name.sys.assembly_files;
```

To do it dynamically (or in a loop, or whatever):

```
DECLARE @dbname sysname,
        @exec nvarchar(1000);

SET @dbname = N'database_name';
SET @exec = QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

EXEC @exec N'SELECT DB_NAME(), <cols> FROM sys.assembly_files;';
```

Entered on a phone, so sorry if any typos.

Comment: Your solution is what I was looking for. Thanks a ton for your quick help.

Comment: The one everyone always forgets: the procedure name can be parameterized, and `sp_executesql` is actually in the `sys` schema so works with this. I think you should make an article on that

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do, here's some powershell that will get the details for all files for all (non-system) assemblies in all user databases:

```
$s = Connect-DbaInstance -SqlInstance .;

foreach ($db in $s.Databases) {
   foreach ($a in $db.Assemblies | where IsSystemObject -eq $false) {
      $a.SqlAssemblyFiles;
   }
}
```

I'm using `Connect-DbaInstance` from [dbatools](https://dbatools.io) to get an SMO Server object, but you're welcome to do that however you'd like.